# Fields that are not finite extensions of proper subfields

Tags: fields, non-archimedean-fields

What fields are not finite extensions of proper subfields? Prime fields and (less obviously) real closed fields have this property. Do the $p$-adics enjoy this property as well?

Comment: I think the fields $\Bbb Q_p$ do indeed have that property, but the argument has escaped me. Stay tuned.

Comment: The argument by Lubin is an answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2893911/subfields-of-the-p-adic-numbers.

Comment: Thus you observe, @user1728, senile dementia striking once again. But thanks for saving me the mind-work of reconstructing the argument.

Comment: The following paper of Jarden and Videla discusses several examples of fields with this property: https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/article/JTNB_2016__28_1_213_0.pdf